# TimeConstrained[Delete[Range[1],1]] causes kernel crash

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, kernel, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

Run these two samples of code here (AFTER SAVING YOUR CURRENT WORK):

```
Do[
 TimeConstrained[
   While[True,
     Delete[{1}, 1];
     ];,
   0.1];,
 {100}]
```

---

```
Do[
 TimeConstrained[
   While[True,
     Delete[Range[1], 1];
     ];,
   0.1];,
 {100}]
```

When I run the second one, the kernel  crashes.  WTH?

Some details.

- This works for a `Range` of any size.
- It doesn't happen every time `TimeConstrained` is run, which is why I put it in a `Table` to guarantee a crash.
- It happens no matter what the timeout is, I just chose 0.1 to make the crash happen sooner.

  - This is actually significant, it means whatever the problem is happens when `TimeConstrained` times out.
- It also won't happen if you replace `Delete` with `Drop[Range[1], {1}]`.

I encounter this problem while writing a benchmark that compares, among other things, `Drop` to `Delete`.  I'd like to avoid just dropping `Delete` from all of my test cases.

### Tested Versions

Crashes on:

- 10.0.0, Windows 8.1 64-bit
- 10.0.1, Windows 8.1 64-bit
- 10.0.2, Mac OS X 10.10.2
- 10.1.0, Max OS X 10.10.2
- 10.3.1, Linux (Raspian)
- 10.4.1, Windows 7 x64, Windows 10
- 11.0.0, Windows 10
- 11.0.1, Windows 7 x64

Not on:

- 8.0.4, Windows 7 x64
- 9.0.0.0, Linux x86-64
- 10.0.2, Linux
- 11.1.0, Windows 10 64-bit

### Updates

April 2015: I contacted Wolfram, they say they are aware of the bug.

April 2017: Wolfram emailed me letting me know that "We believe that the issue has been resolved in the current 11.1 release of Mathematica."

Comment: Can confirm crash on Windows 8.1 Mathematica V10.0.2.0.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus That's good to know, I was worried that all the stuff I did getting `Compile` to work had borked my system!

Comment: Nothing happens on Mathematica 10.0.2 on Linux!

Comment: Interesting... I'm going to try and update to 10.0.1 (school license... can't get 10.0.2) and see if that helps.

Comment: Same as DumpsterDoofus.

Comment: 10.0.1 has the same issue.  Maybe I should just buy 10.0.2.... I'll have to when I graduate anyway.  Can someone test 10.0.2 on Windows?

Comment: Kernel crashes in V10.0.2, Mac OSX 10.10.2.

Comment: No problem on v9.0.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit).

Comment: Replicated and reported.

Comment: This bug still exists in 10.4.1 on Windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the [just released](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/03/16/the-rd-pipeline-continues-launching-version-11-1/) Mathematica 11.1.

```
Do[
 TimeConstrained[While[True, Delete[Range[1], 1];];, 
   0.1];, {100}]; "done"

(* "done" *)
```